# Unable to pass value from Private to Public Sub

Tags: vba, excel

I have a tool which I am designing to present a number of questions to a user in a set of userforms.  The form will generate a score via passing an integer result from the userform to a main sub, which passes the code to a worksheet.  My problem is the Main module doesn't get the values passed from the private module, what is going on here?

I first tried to do this using boolean values which didn't pass, now I am trying to do it using integer results which also don't pass.

User Form Code:

```
Private Sub Image1_Click()
Select Case MsgBox("You have picked Thinks Commercially, is this correct?", vbYesNo, "Please Confirm")
    Case VbMsgBoxResult.vbYes
         Call Main.CountResults(ThinksCommerciallyInt = 1, OptimisesTalentInt = 0, DeliversPIInt = 0, DrivesExecutionInt = 0, ChampionsChangeInt = 0, OperatesColInt = 0)
         UserForm1.Hide
         UserForm2.Show
    Case VbMsgBoxResult.vbNo
         MsgBox ("Please Select Again")
End Select
End Sub
```

Main Sub Code

```
Public Sub CountResults(ThinksCommerciallyInt As Integer, OptimisesTalentInt As Integer, DeliversPIInt As Integer, DrivesExecutionInt As Integer, ChampionsChangeInt As Integer, OperatesColInt As Integer)

If ThinksCommerciallyInt = 1 Then
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Config").Range("B2").Value = ThinksCommerciallyInt
ThinksCommerciallyInt = ThinksCommerciallyInt + 1
ThinksCommerciallyInt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Config").Range("B2").Value
End If

If OptimisesTalentInt = 1 Then
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Config").Range("B3").Value = OptimisesTalentInt
OptimisesTalentInt = OptimisesTalentInt + 1
OptimisesTalentInt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Config").Range("B3").Value
End If

If DeliversPIInt = 1 Then
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Config").Range("B4").Value = DeliversPIInt
DeliversPIInt = DeliversPIInt + 1
DeliversPIInt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Config").Range("B4").Value
End If

If DrivesExecutionInt = 1 Then
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Config").Range("B5").Value = DrivesExecutionInt
DrivesExecutionInt = DrivesExecutionInt + 1
DrivesExecutionInt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Config").Range("B5").Value
End If

If ChampionsChangeInt = 1 Then
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Config").Range("B6").Value = ChampionsChangeInt
ChampionsChangeInt = ChampionsChangeInt + 1
ChampionsChangeInt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Config").Range("B6").Value
End If

If OperatesColInt = 1 Then
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Config").Range("B7").Value = OperatesColInt
OperatesColInt = OperatesColInt + 1
OperatesColInt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Config").Range("B7").Value
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: yes it is, rather than write instances individually I put them into a single subroutine located under a module called Main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your calling code:

```
ThinksCommerciallyInt = 1
```

should be

```
ThinksCommerciallyInt := 1
```

similarly for the other parameters